# Do we have an inertial frame?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, inertial-frames

If newtons law applies without pseudo forces then we're in an inertial frame.
So theoretically we've an inertial frame.

What about practically finding one? Earth is not, probably neither the sun. Then where can I find a place to be inertial?

Comment: You can't. What you can do, according to general relativity, is approximate your frame of reference as a local, small inertial frame but of course how well you do depends on the detail of your approximation.

Comment: In GR, a free falling observer is in an inertial frame.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any true inertial reference frame in the universe?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17459/)

Comment: In GR, a free-falling frame is inertial assuming it's small compared to the curvature