# What would happen if we did a Newton's bucket experiment in the closest accessible approximation to "empty space?"

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, reference-frames, machs-principle

I will get right to the question; for readers unfamiliar with its genesis, I append a background section below.

I want to know how testable the prediction is that the water in a rotating bucket would experience a centrifugal pseudo force in the closest approximation to empty space we have access to (i.e., as far away from the Solar System as we could reasonably deploy a suitable test station).  I envision the simplest possible experimental design, along the lines of the one described in the following post:

[https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/416011/newtons-bucket-artificial-gravity-absolute-rotation-and-machs-principle][1]

A fancy satellite experiment has been done in near-Earth orbit (Gravity Probe B, launched in 2004 with data collection continuing until 2011).  As I understand it, the results were consistent with predictions of standard GR: the so-called Lense–Thirring effect, which dominated behavior of the gyroscopes on the satellite, arose almost entirely  from the effects of Earth's rotation on adjacent spacetime.

So, let's get as far away from local masses as possible and see how well standard GR's predictions hold up. Is this idea ridiculous?

*Background to the question*

In its simplest variant, a Newton's bucket experiment involves spinning a bucket of water in Earth's gravitational field and observing that the surface of the water is not flat due the centrifugal pseudo force.  In this case, it is obvious that the bucket is spinning relative to the patch of Earth's surface underneath it.

Einstein attributed his development of general relativity (GR), in part, to the thought experiment of spinning the bucket in "empty space" where there is no obvious way to determine whether or not the bucket is actually spinning.  Mach had earlier posed a version of this thought experiment; he invoked distant celestial objects (e.g., stars) as defining a reference frame relative to which the bucket's rotational motion could be judged.

There is a HUGE subsequent literature about whether or not distant celestial objects are relevant to behavior of the water in the bucket.  As I understand it, distant celestial  objects are not relevant in mainstream variants of GR.

The issue has been addressed dozens of time on the Physics Stack Exchange.  In my survey of these previous posts, no one attempts to answer my empirically oriented question in their responses to them.  All of them seem to pose the problem as one of prediction rather than observational testing of predictions.

Comment: What are you asking? How to test MOND with a satellite? My understanding is that it can't be tested within the Milky Way (that way). We would need to go "outside", first.

Comment: MOND (Modified Newtonian Dynamics) is one alternative to standard GR, but there seem to be many others--for example, Brans-Dicke, which adds a scalar field to the tensor field of standard GR and was explictly motivated to provide a mechanism via which the mass distribution in the universe could establish an absolute reference frame.  Your comment is helpful in that it suggests that calclulations have been done indicating that a test of the type I propose would not distinguish between MOND and GR.  I will try to track down the relevant references.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is clear that your underlying question is the validity of Mach's principle in the context of General Theory of Relativity (GR). It is known that Einstein was quite enamoured with Mach's principle and tried to formulate GR to satisfy it in a more general way.

However, it seems to be the case that GR does not satisfy Mach's principle. This is easy to see in the solution of the Kerr black hole, whereby the angular momentum of the black hole plays a rôle, even as the spacetime asymptotically approaches Minkowski spacetime far away. There is no distant stars in the solution of the ideal Kerr black hole. This means that the solution for the Newton's bucket problem in GR should have bulges to account for centripetal acceleration, even though it would not in any way look like the usual stuff we see on Earth.

A good textbook on GR would emphasise that the solution to a rotating system in GR is not obtained by taking Minkowski spacetime and setting it to rotate.

Comment: This answer, together with Jan Lalinski's, is helpful.  To get further, I would probably need to do my own GR calculations.  I find it interesting that your answer essentially says Mach's idea was wrong (since a rotating object will have an equatorial bulge without reference to cosmic structure), while Jan's answer says that there might be something to Mach's idea but it is impossible to test.  Both of you seem to agree that my expensive bucket experiment would be likely to produce the result predicted by GR no matter where it is carried out.    Thanks.

Comment: That is partly because we think GR is the correct theory to appeal to. Which is the correct thing to do in physics: until experiment forces us to consider complications, pick the simplest theory that is already accepted by the consensus. Theorising is very difficult!

Answer (score 2):

> What would happen if we did a Newton's bucket experiment in the closest accessible approximation to "empty space" ?

You're missing the whole point of an experiment.

The whole point of performing an experiment is to make measurements and ideally you do not draw your conclusions before looking at the data and comparing it with what your existing theory predicts and if any differences are significant (there's statistical math for doing that formally).

You're asking us to *imagine* the experiment and predict it's result.  We're just going to predict the result you already know the theory predicts.  It would be expected to match GR's predictions.

That's all we can say without actually performing an experiment.  Which we cannot current do.

> I want to know how testable the prediction is that the water in a rotating bucket would experience a centrifugal pseudo force in the closest approximation to empty space we have access to (i.e., as far away from the Solar System as we could reasonably deploy a suitable test station).

It's not testable now and probably not testable in the foreseeable future.

At the time of writing we can just about get a space station in orbit around Earth, so not even outside the solar system, let alone far away.  This is unlikely to change for decades, if not longer.

So you're asking about an experiment we cannot implement.

> no one attempts to answer my empirically oriented question

That requires empirical data.  We cannot access the data you want because the experiment you want is beyond our capability, so we cannot answer you in the manner you want.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your point.  Much of the activity in today's observational and experimental science goes into assessing the feasibility of testing theories that are hard to test.  Different alternatives to standard GR evidently make different predictions about how an experiment of the sort I describe would come out.  Tests would have to get away from low-Earth orbit, but I cannot find any calculations showing how far away.  Gravity B seems to have been a big success; it took ~50 years from the time it was planned to publication of data.  I just want a Gravity C.

Comment: @Caveman I have tried to explain why your question is, IMO, unanswerable here on Physics SE.  I do not see how you expect us to provide an empirical answer when the question is about a test we cannot perform in the manner you want.  Empirical answers require empirical data.

Answer (score 2):

Inertia in Mach's idea is not likely to be due to local masses in the Solar system, because those are distributed in non-isotropic manner and inertia seems isotropic. So if other bodies cause inertia, it seems it's all the distant bodies that have almost isotropic distribution. Doing Newton's bucket experiments far from the Solar system is unlikely to discover that inertia is different there.

Mach's principle is an interesting theoretical idea, but unfortunately, in practice it seems immensely difficult to test experimentally. We don't know how to get outside the material envelope (stars, dust, radiation) which according to Mach is responsible for the inertia.