# What exactly is meant by saying that two events had been "simultaneous in an inertial frame"?

Tags: special-relativity, experimental-physics, terminology, relativity

In order to address my question based on a concrete example setup let the following two separate events be given:

- participants $A$ and $J$ encountering each other in passing (additional participants may be considered). The details of this event $\varepsilon_{AJ}$ were widely observable: participant $A$'s indication "$A_J$" as a distinctive "sparkle", and participant $J$'s indication "$J_A$" as a distinctive "flicker",
- participants $B$ and $K$ encountering each other in passing (additional participants may be considered). The details of this event $\varepsilon_{BK}$ were widely observable: participant $B$'s indication "$B_K$" as a distinctive "twinkle", and participant $K$'s indication "$K_B$" as a distinctive "flash".

Let participants $A$ and $B$ having been and remained at rest to each other (but not to participants $J$ or $K$); and (likewise) participants $J$ and $K$ having been and remained at rest to each other (but not to participants $A$ or $B$).

Let participant $M$ be identified as "(located at the) midpoint between" $A$ and $B$ (for short: as "the middle between" $A$ and $B$), and let participant $N$ be identified as "the middle between" $J$ and $K$.

Further, it is given that participant $M$ observed (the signal fronts of) (all relevant details of) both events, $\varepsilon_{AJ}$ and $\varepsilon_{BK}$, in coincidence;
and on the other hand that participant $N$ first observed (the signal fronts of) (all relevant details of) event $\varepsilon_{AJ}$, and only subsequently event $\varepsilon_{BK}$.

It can be concluded that

(1) participants $A$, $B$ and $M$ were jointly members of an [inertial frame (in the sense of Rindler)](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Special_relativity:_kinematics),

(2) participants $J$, $K$ and $N$ were jointly members of an inertial frame,

(3) participant $M$ was not identifiable as "the middle between" $J$ and $K$,

(4) participant $N$ was not identifiable as "the middle between" $A$ and $B$,

and following [Einstein's coordinate-free definition of how to determine "simultaneity"](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Relativity:_The_Special_and_General_Theory/Part_I#Section_8_-_On_the_Idea_of_Time_in_Physics) that

(5) participant $A$'s indication $A_J$ and participant $B$'s indication $B_K$ were simultaneous, and

(6) participant $J$'s indication $J_A$ and participant $K$'s indication $K_B$ were not simultaneous.

Now, a phrase which seems related and which is [encountered quite frequently](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22simultaneous+in%22) is that

> "*(two) events were simultaneous in a (particular inertial) frame*"

and I'd like to understand whether and how this phrase might be used in case of the described example setup. Therefore:

**Two specific Questions:**

Regarding the given example setup would it be considered appropriate to say:

> "*events $\varepsilon_{AJ}$ and $\varepsilon_{BK}$ were simultaneous in the inertial frame of participants $A$, $B$, $M$*"

?

And if so:
Is thereby anything implied besides the conclusions (1) -- (6) listed above, or even contradicting these conclusions (1) -- (6)
(for instance, might be implied that it is appropriate to say:

> - "*participant $M$ was the middle between $J$ and $K$, in the inertial frame of participants $A$, $B$, $M$*", or
> - "*participant $J$'s indication $J_A$ and participant $K$'s indication $K_B$ were simultaneous in the inertial frame of participants $A$, $B$, $M$*", or
> - "*participant $N$ was the middle between $A$ and $B$, in the inertial frame of participants $J$, $K$, $N$*", or
> - "*participant $A$'s indication $A_J$ and participant $B$'s indication $B_K$ were not simultaneous in the inertial frame of participants $J$, $K$, $N$*"

)
?

**Post scriptum**
for ready reference, and in response to comments by @Angelika :

The wording of Einstein's coordinate-free definition of "simultaneity" reads:

> [*[An] observer placed at the mid-point $M$ of the distance $AB$ [...] If the observer perceives the two flashes of lightning at the same time, then they are simultaneous.* 
>  
>  Albert Einstein, Relativity: "The Special and General Theory", Section 8: "On the Idea of Time in Physics"  (1917), translated by R. W. Lawson](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Relativity:_The_Special_and_General_Theory/Part_I#Section_8_-_On_the_Idea_of_Time_in_Physics)

In application of this definition to the example setup described in the OP above therefore

- participant $M$, being the "middle between" participants $A$ and $B$, has the privilege and business of judging whether and which indications of $A$ and of $B$ were "simultaneous", or not; and likewise
- participant $N$, being the "middle between" participants $J$ and $K$, has the privilege and business of judging whether and which indications of $J$ and of $K$ were "simultaneous", or not.

$M$'s verdict concerning specificly $A$'s "sparkle" indication $A_J$ and $B$'s "twinkle" indication $B_K$ is:
these two indications were simultaneous; as listed in (5) above.
$N$'s verdict concerning specificly $J$'s "flicker" indication $J_A$ and $K$'s "flash" indication $K_B$ is:
these two indications were not simultaneous; as listed in (6) above.

Comment: @Angelika: "_could you elaborate the difference between $A$'s indication and $J$'s? [...]_" -- Besides calling them distinctive "sparkle" vs. "flicker", and distinguishing them in notation: $A_J$ vs. $J_A$ ? Well, I can make up another, perhaps more impressive example derived from [Einstein's original](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/On_the_Electrodynamics_of_Moving_Bodies_%281920_edition%29#.C2.A7_1._Definition_of_Synchronism.): "The locomotive and I met/passed each other, as the locomotive honked and I got startled.". (It wasn't me who honked; and the locomotive didn't get and look startled).

Comment: @Angelika: "_I [am] really not getting your concept of $M$'s or $N$'s "business or privilege to judge"_" -- Then how do you interpret the phrasing of Einstein's defintion: ["_If the observer perceives ... then ..._"](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Relativity:_The_Special_and_General_Theory/Part_I#Section_8_-_On_the_Idea_of_Time_in_Physics) ?? (Then whose privilege and business is the determination of simultaneity, or of dis-simultaneity, instead, **if not** that of the mentioned "_observer placed in/at the middle_" ??)

Comment: @Angelika: "_[...] right that $M$ doesn't determine simultaneity in $N$'s frame and vice-versa._" -- O.k. So: $~~~~$ $M$ doesn't determine/assert/judge simultaneity of entire events, and neither does $N$, and consequently saying that "entire events were simultaneous, or entire events were dis-simultaneous (in one frame, or the other)" is meaningless or at best an imprecise rendition of the conclusions (5) and (6) stated in the OP. Correct?

Comment: @Angelika: "_In the statements 5 and 6 frames are not mentioned._" -- "Frames" are mentioned in already in (1) and (2); e.g. "(1) participants $A$, $B$ [...] were jointly members of an inertial frame"; and $A$ and $B$ are of course explicitly mentioned in (5). (Likewise $J$, $K$ in statements (2) and (6).) "_I think its assumed that $M$ can receive indications of $A$ and $B$ only and not of $J$ and_ $K$" -- Wrong. $M$ observed all that, in coincidence. "_or $M$ doesn't "know" about the frame of_ $J, K, N$" -- $M$ and $N$ even met/passed each other. $M$ is just not "middle between" $J$ and $K$.

Comment: Yes M is not the middle between J and K it can never be. And there is no wrong if M "judges" the signals of J and K, the signals which were given at the instant of meeting. You are just making the same indication different in the two different inertial frames. Why not think like this, when A met J they touched each other to produce a spark or flash whatever it is. It is the same indication of **that particular event of meeting**

Comment: If A, B, J and K gives indications at any time other than the instant of meeting, there is no use of judging those indications for they are not the indications of the meeting events and simultaneity won't be determined. Any signal J and K gives at the same time in JKN frame will always be simultaneous to N but not to M. And same is true for the signals of A and B to M. But the **particular indications of meetings** are same for A and J; and B and K. Indications have to come from events like meeting in this example and not randomly at any other time.

Comment: @Angelika: "_Why not think like this, when $A$ met $J$ they touched each other [...] the particular indications of meetings are same for $A$ and_ $J$" -- Well, as long as you admit that all participants are and remain distinct, even at meetings/passings (and of course everyone is always meeting/passing some others) we can still speak of "$A$, at the meeting/passing of $J$" vs. "$J$, at the meeting/passing of $A$"; resolving event $\varepsilon_{AJ}$ into indications $A_J$ vs. $J_A$. But if we're not even supposed to distinguish "who honked" vs. "who hollered" at some meeting/passing ... then ??

Comment: Its right that $M$ is not middle of $J,K$ or $N$ is not middle of $A,B$. Its right that $M$ will meet $N$ once. If $M$ judges $J's$ and $K's$ **indications of meetings**, what problem will it bring in determining simultaneity of the meeting events? Infact, $M$ will never know which indication is who's? unless $M$ can identify and distinguish the indications by "knowing" them beforehand, perhaps by a "pre-plan" with $A$ and $B$.

Comment: @Angelika: "_what problem will it bring_" -- "Problems" are not mentioned in my OP question; your remark is rather concerned with the motivation for asking. Yes, I consider it a problem if differently defined notions are given the same "overloaded" name (such as speaking of "simultaneous events", event though $M$ is not "the middle between events $\varepsilon_{AJ}$ and $\varepsilon_{BK}$"). I consider a problem what detracts from [the details of how to determine "mutual rest" etc.](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/3193/what-determines-which-frames-are-inertial-frames/70646#70646).

Answer (score 1):

I would like to bring the [ladder paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladder_paradox) here to explain simultaneity of events.
A ladder (an inertial frame) is moving horizontally with a relatively high constant speed with respect to a garage (another inertial frame). The garage has an open door where the ladder can not actually enter if the ladder was at rest in the garage's frame but that is not important. Now the two **events**:
1. First end of the ladder touches first side of the door.
2. Second end of the ladder touches second side of the door.
In the garage's frame of reference, the ladder undergoes a Lorentz length contraction such that the above two events happens simultaneously while in the ladder frame of reference, the door width undergoes a Lorentz length contraction and the above two events doesn't happen simultaneously.
So, whether two events are simultaneous depends on your choice of reference frame.
I can now think in this way:
$A$ and $B$ are standing at the first and second sides of the door respectively of the garage while $M$ is at the middle of $A$ and $B$ in the garage reference frame and $J$ and $K$ are standing at the first and second end of the ladder respectively while $N$ is at the middle of $J$ and $K$ in the ladder reference frame.
So, the answers to your specific questions are:
events $ε_{AJ}$ and $ε_{BK}$ were simultaneous in the inertial frame of participants $A, B, M$ since all the indications reached $M$ at the same time in the inertial frame of participants $A, B, M$ but the events were not simultaneous in the inertial frame of participants $J, K, N$ since the indications reach $N$ at different times in the inertial frame of participants $J, K, N$.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22924/discussion-on-answer-by-angelika-what-exactly-is-meant-by-saying-that-two-events). (And just to make sure it's clear, this is also an instruction not to continue the discussion in the comments.)

Comment: @Marco Ocram: _"You seem to be fixated on this [...]"_ -- Thanks for noting; sorry for my response/rebuttal being late. _"imagine two reference frames with coincident x and x' axes."_ -- Conventionally either of these axes is mutually "the axis in direction of motion of the other frame". _"Since the axes are not physical objects, [...]"_ -- I disagree (to this sort of imagination) and once again quote W. Rindler: ["_An inertial frame is simply an infinite set of point particles sitting still in space relative to each other_"](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Special_relativity:_kinematics).

Comment: @Marco Ocram: _"Why not forget about trains etc. altogether. [...]"_ -- Counter-proposal: Start liking it!, follow Einstein's lead: ["_All our verifications amount to determination of space-time coincidences {... such as ...}  meetings of material points._"](http://einsteinpapers.press.princeton.edu/vol6-trans/165?highlightText=coincidences). Attribute distinct portions of any one coincidence event to its distinct participants: The event of "a match head striking a match box" consists of the indication of the match head igniting **distinct from** the indication of the match box being scratched

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your assertions:

> Events $\varepsilon_{AJ}$ and $\varepsilon_{BK}$ were simultaneous in the inertial frame of participants $A$, $B$, $M$.

This is a perfectly reasonable statement and it is the sort of language used in everyday physics.

> Participant $M$ was the middle between $J$ and $K$, in the inertial frame of participants $A$, $B$, $M$.

This is not entirely a reasonable statement, though, because in the inertial frame of $A$, $B$ and $M$, $M$ can only be in the middle of $J$ and $K$ at a single specific time, so you'd need to specify that. A complicated and technical way to phrase it would be

> - There exists an event $\varepsilon_M$ at which $M$ observes herself to be equidistant and collinear with $J$ and $K$; this event is simultaneous with $\varepsilon_{AJ}$ and $\varepsilon_{BK}$ in the inertial frame of participants $A$, $B$, $M$.

Less technically, you could say that $M$ passes through the middle of $J$ and $K$ at the same time as the flashes and sparkles happen, as observed in the frame of $A$ and $B$.

Note that terms like "collinear" and "equidistant" are tricky to define, because you're specifying distances to other objects which may be moving with respect to you, so you need to specify equidistance with respect to what times of observation - i.e. equidistance to events, not objects, where you observe the events as simultaneous.

Your third statement, on the other hand,

> Participant $J$'s indication $J_A$ and participant $K$'s indication $K_B$ were simultaneous in the inertial frame of participants $A$, $B$, and $M$

is perfectly fine.

Your last two statements,

> Participant $N$ was the middle between $A$ and $B$, in the inertial frame of participants $J$, $K$, $N$
>
> Participant $A$'s indication $A_J$ and participant $B$'s indication $B_K$ were not simultaneous in the inertial frame of participants $J$, $K$, $N$

behave the same as the previous two.

Comment: Emilio Pisanty: "_you could say that $M$ passes through the middle of $J$ and_ $K$" -- Right (a general consenquence in the given example, too):  $M$ and $N$ met/passed each other (event $\varepsilon_{MN}$).  But does this make $N$ strictly being "[placed at the mid-point of the distance AB {... as observer who} perceives the two flashes of lightning at the same time](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Relativity:_The_Special_and_General_Theory/Part_I#Section_8_-_On_the_Idea_of_Time_in_Physics)", to use Einstein's exact wording? Does it make $M$ "placed at the mid-point of the distance JK" ??

Comment: Emilio Pisanty: "_A complicated and technical way to phrase it_" -- +1 for trying to answer as rigorously as I intended to ask. "$\bullet~$ _There exists an event [...] which $M$ observes herself to be equidistant and collinear with $J$ and_ $K$" -- You're attributing "distance" values to pairs ($M$ and $J$, or $M$ and $K$) who aren't even at rest to each other ?? That's **improper**! You're suggesting that geometric relations (of 3 part.s) might be "_observed by_" (only) one of them ($M$), at (only) one event ?? $N$, $J$ and $K$ **measured** their relation! (And $M$ only met/passed $N$ once.)

Comment: Emilio Pisanty: "`" -` _Participant $M$ was the middle between $J$ and $K$, in the inertial frame of participants $A$, $B$, $M$.`"` This is not entirely a reasonable statement, though, because [...]_" -- Indeed. Consequently the statement `"`Entire events were simultaneous (in some inertial frame)`"` seems either similarly "_not entirely reasonable_" and/or not using the notion `"`simultaneous`"` exactly as Einstein defined it ("Relativity", **Section 8**, linked in the OP question).