# Is there some kind of aether for rotations only?

Tags: rotation, inertial-frames, relative-motion, aether

Currently I'm reading "A briefer history of time". I understand how the Michelson–Morley experiment refutes the theory of an aether (like in "absolute frame of reference") for translation in space and that relativity makes sense of this.

But what about rotations? Even in outer space letting a spaceship rotate creates artificial gravity via centripetal acceleration. To me this sound like there is an absolute frame of reference for rotations. If this is correct, how is it determined?

(Sorry if the question is to stupid for this platform.)

Comment: some relevant search terms: Newton's bucket, Mach's principle

Comment: Related question [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5483/is-machs-principle-wrong).

Comment: My view is that there's nothing to this issue at all. We already know the acceleration is absolute. The fact that rotation is absolute says nothing new, because rotation is just a special form of acceleration (i.e. the kind that makes you go in a circle). But this seems fairly controversial and you'll find plenty of people who disagree. It's apparently subtle in philosophy.

Comment: How does an aether relate to your observation? What part does it play?

Comment: Related: [How does a spinning object “know” that it is spinning?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/239477)

Comment: Thanks for the search terms and links. I think I will get along fine now.