Meaning of of inertial frames in special relativity
One of the postulates of special relativity is
The laws of physics are the same in all inertial frames
There is a mention of inertial frames in the postulate. But the predictions of relativity are clearly against the classical mechanics devised by Galileo and Newton,denying the absolute nature of space and time.
Therefore the definition used in Newtonian mechanics certainly cannot be used to define inertial frames.
Then how are inertial frames defined in special theory of relativity?

Does this answer your question? Inertial frames of reference

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3193/2451 and links therein.
